# Why the file manager App didn't work when using Intent.ACTION_PICK in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing in Android , and I want to implement a text file select.

I have install es file manager App in my Android phone.

I add the permission :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` , and I try the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK );
intent.setType( "text/*" );
Intent destIntent = Intent.createChooser( intent, "Select File" );
startActivityForResult( destIntent, 0 );
```

But it didn't open the file manager and list the file let me choose.

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manifest permission??

Comment: You need the permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Default file manager cant handle this Intent `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. You have to install [es file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) or similar file manager apps form app store in your device to open that intent.

Comment: I have install es file explorer.