# Accessing File Manager through an app

Tags: android

i want to know how to access the file manager through my app. Here is my code

```
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Android does not have a file manager. There is no requirement for an Android device to have an app that handles that particular `Intent` structure.

Comment: This seens to be a recurrent question, maybe you should check at: [Why the file manager App didn't work when using Intent.ACTION_PICK in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313460/why-the-file-manager-app-didnt-work-when-using-intent-action-pick-in-android) or perhaps, [Android file chooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser).